# "please leave a comment" suppresses "you have x votes remaining today"

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, design

When you downvote, that can potentially trigger several distinct popups:

- "you have x votes remaining today"
- "questions need votes too" (if your last question-vote was a bit long ago)
- "please leave a comment" (only when you are low-rep)

The problem is that "please leave a comment" suppresses the probably more important "you have x votes remaining today".
(Not sure whether "questions need votes too" has the same problem.)

Could those be merged or at least the votes-remaining warning prioritized?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has already been asked here.. Can't find it though.

Comment: You're already warned when you fall below 6 remaining votes (up or down). At least from my experience, but I don't believe that's a privilege.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that was also my thought but maybe you only get one message? Either the *leave a comment* **OR** the *6 votes remaining* . It has been a while since I was that low on rep...

Comment: @rene I think that's the problem for many here - it's been a while since they had that low a rep!

Comment: True, but I'm to lazy to login with my sock-puppet ...

Comment: @rene: Oh, I see now how you got all this rep then. I'm going to alert SO moderators right away! :)

Comment: @rene -Yes, I've updated the question, the suggestion message overwrites the votes remaining message. "It shouldn't be that difficult to implement... Should it?" (Famous last words)

Comment: @user, obviously upvoting was not enough, so I tried to further clarify your question. I believe the downvotes it has accumulated were only the result of misunderstanding, please don't take them at face value.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks for the edit. It's a lot clearer now. Last time I edited, it was this which I tried to say. I didn't know whether to mark it as a bug fix or a feature.

Comment: @user, I'm also split on that, so I left your `[feature-request]` tag.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Did a complete rewrite.

Comment: Is the vote cap really rep based? I got this a lot because I vote frivolously. It keeps reminding you with each vote then you get below 6 votes remaining, so it should happen with every vote.

Comment: I think it is more important to teach a low rep user how to use the site properly than it is to give them a piece of information that usually isn't relevant. That said, there should be a mechanism to stack them so they get both pieces.

Comment: Personally, I don't think a rep of 800 is relatively "low" compared to the influx of new students. Compared to the old-timers it is, but I know how to use the site by now! Though I agree, stacking is the best option rather than one take precedence

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've changed the code so that if multiple messages are generated by upvoting and downvoting, they will all be shown, in a `<ul>`. Additionally, the message box won't auto-dismiss in that case, to give you more time to read.

This will be deployed as of build 3746 on MSE/MSO, and build 2869 on other sites.

Comment: Question: is there anywhere we can find the current version and build data of the public site?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Yep, look at the footer, where it currently says "rev 2015.10.6.3745".

Comment: Ah, never noticed that. Ta.